# Defining target for Supervised learning classification

Tags: classification, dataset, supervised-learning

I would like to know if there is a way to predict an outcome (successful/failed or $1/0$) with and without a binary variable and compare their predict probability.

I have several variables. However, I consider only one of them: it is a binary variable indicating
$$
X=\left\{\array{1 & \textrm{if proposition was made}\\0 & \textrm{otherwise}}\right.
$$
The outcome $Y$ is whether the contract was successful, i.e.
$$
Y=\left\{\array{1 & \textrm{if contract successful}\\0 & \textrm{otherwise}}\right.
$$

What I want is actually to know in the future if I should propose or not the supplement, i.e. whether to set $X=1$ or rather $X=0$. Because sometimes when it is proposed ($X=1$) the contract is not successful ($Y=0$).

Answer (score 0):

Quite basic approach is to calculate the probability of success for both possibilities
$P(Y=1|X=0) = \frac{N_{X=0 \land Y=1}}{N_{X=0}}$

$P(Y=1|X=1) = \frac{N_{X=1 \land Y=1}}{N_{X=1}}$

where $N_{\textrm{statement}}$ stands for number of records where statement was true.

After this, you can pick $X=0$ or $X=1$ for which the probability is higher.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. How can I have the probability for both of these possibilities for each observations with a ML model ?

Comment: I thought of outputing the 2 probabilities in the two cases by putting X equal to 0 or 1 to simulate the two cases.

Comment: $P(Y=0|X=1)=1-P(Y=1|X=1)$ Does it help?